# Twitter count parameter

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to write some code that will send a search request to twitter.

However, the return seems to be ignored the parameters that I'm putting into the URL (except the actual search query).

The url I'm using is:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=obama&src=typd&count=4&tresult_type=popular
```

The count just returns 20 though, regardless of what I enter, and I'm fairly sure the popular but isn't being returned either.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no count parameter in Twitter Search API. Check their documentation: [Twitter API: search](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search)

You can use the rpp (results per page) to achieve what you want in the 1.0 API:

> http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=obama&rpp=4&tresult_type=popular

Or with the new 1.1 API:

> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=obama&count=4&tresult_type=popular

Comment: I think you may be using the outdated API 1.0 version.
It was changed to count for the new one:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets

Comment: @Incredidave I thought you were using it. The new 1.1 API has different url (api.twitter.com). Check the documentation:  [link](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets). User authentication is required in the new API.

Comment: I'm using the new URL, am I not?

And I already do OAuth, it works fine. The only problem is it seems to ignore the extra parameters I put into the URL.

Comment: Read the documentation, the base for the new API is api.twitter.com/1.1/.

Comment: Ah, that works, thanks. Took a while to test because it changes the format for all the data you pull, but it works.
I'm not quite sure what the popular tag does though, the tweets I'm getting just seem to be the most recent ones.

Anyway, thanks for the help.